# Python dictionaries: trouble prompting user through directory

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested, nested-lists

I am new to programming. This is my first attempt at a project that I may be able to use at work.

My thought is to automate a document numbering system/document control as much as possible.

I have my dictionaries setup to represent the file structure. I have prompted the user for location, project#, Department. I tried to simplify the input() to only be a single letter the use `startswith()` to find the key I needed. It worked in the snip below but cant get it to work again. The for loop and if statement in the last line have me stumped.

I feel like I'm doing this a hard way.

```
# prompt user for location
Location_Input = input(f"Enter Location ({', '.join([f'{k}={v}' for k, v in Location.items()])}): ")
if Location_Input in Location:
    # prompt user for project number
    Project_Number_Input = input(
        f"Enter Project Number ({', '.join([f'{k}={v}' for k, v in Project_Number.items()])}): ")
    if Project_Number_Input in Project_Number:
        # Prompt the user to select a department
        department_options = Departments
        department_options_str = ", ".join(department_options)
        department = input(f"Enter the Department name ({department_options_str}): ")
        matching_departments = {}
        for key in department_options:
            if key.startswith(department) and key in Departments:
                matching_departments[key] = department_options[key]
                division_options = matching_departments[key]

divisions = {}
                for div in division_options:
                    if div in matching_departments and div.startswith(selected_division)
```

I tried the ifinstance as well from advice here. No luck.
I've tried calling .keys(), items(), values(),

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you are trying to do?

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided (simplified) samples of Location, Project_Number and Departments, explain how you intend divisions dictionary to be used and what the result of the code should be.

Comment: I am trying to  navigate a user through a folder structure until they reach the particular document type needed. The second half of my code stores the keys of the inputs and concatenates them to form a document number. 
It then assigns a document number saves the new number to a spread sheet

Comment: Sorry hit send too quickly. 
The goal is to help with assigning numbers to drawings across multiple disciplines. 
Prompt a user to enter location, project number department and discipline. 
I’m new to Python can’t really enjoy it
I wanted to add a few lines to document who requested the drawing numbers

Comment: This is a snip from one of the dictionaries. I had them arranged  differently at the start of it. Looking back I think I had it correct then.

Comment: Engineering = {
                  "1_Design Basis": {
                      "1_Facility": {},
                      "2_Pipeline": {}
                  },
                  "2_Civil_Structural": {
                      "1_Drawings": {
                          "0": "Notes & Index",
                          "1": "Plot Plan",

Comment: Location and project are setup the same. Location = {'1: 'TX', '2': NYC, etc}

Comment: Final comment. I have 7 of these dictionaries. Mostly with different structures. I used .updated() to combine them before prompting for the first input.

Comment: Deleted it started over